# Hibernate - OneToMany with Composite key hashcode exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, persistence

I have a @OneToMany relation between `UserDomain` and `PartageDomain`, and the same relation between `FileDomain` and `PartageDomain`. `PartageDomain` has a composite key formed by both the `UserDomain` and the `FileDomain`.
When I try to save a record in the `PartageDomain` table, I get this exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.getHashCode(AbstractType.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.getHashCode(AbstractType.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getHashCode(EntityType.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.engine.EntityKey.generateHashCode(EntityKey.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.EntityKey.<init>(EntityKey.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.getDatabaseSnapshot(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:535)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:535)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:527)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:523)
    at com.stage.dao.PartageDaoImpl.add(PartageDaoImpl.java:39)
    at com.stage.service.PartageServiceImpl.add(PartageServiceImpl.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy42.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.stage.beans.UserManagedBean.saveUserRights(UserManagedBean.java:234)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:102)
    ... 23 more
```

I did some research, and I find that this exception came from three cases :

a) we have a composite key with one of the attributes of the key being an FK to another persistent class.

b) The other persistent class has an ID field whose value is being generated.

c) The instance of the other persistent class is transient (does not yet have an ID)

It's not indicated how we can solve these problems in the documentation, but as advised in the hibernate documentation, I override equals() and hashCode() to implement composite identifier equality. and also also implement Serializable, but it always doesn't work. so if someone has an idea about the source of my problem;

As advised in a comment above, I add the hashcode methods to my `UserDomain` and `FileDomain`, the `getId` and `getLink` methods get the corresponding object Ids.

part of `userDomain`

```
    public class UserDomain implements Serializable {
    ....
    @OneToMany (cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        private Collection<PartageDomain> partageDomain = new ArrayList<PartageDomain>();
    public Collection<PartageDomain> getPartageDomain() {
            return partageDomain;
        }

        public void setPartageDomain(Collection<PartageDomain> partageDomain) {
            this.partageDomain = partageDomain;
        }
public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        UserDomain that = (UserDomain) o;

        if (getId() != null ? !getId().equals(that.getId()) : that.getId() != null) return false;

        return true;
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return (getId() != null ? getId().hashCode() : 0);
    }
```

part of `FileDomain`

```
    public class FileDomain implements Serializable {
    ...
        @OneToMany 
        private Collection<PartageDomain> partageDomain = new ArrayList<PartageDomain>();

        public Collection<PartageDomain> getPartageDomain() {
            return partageDomain;
        }

        public void setPartageDomain(Collection<PartageDomain> partageDomain) {
            this.partageDomain = partageDomain;
        }
public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        FileDomain that = (FileDomain) o;

        if (getLink() != null ? !getLink().equals(that.getLink()) : that.getLink() != null) return false;

        return true;
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return (getLink() != null ? getLink().hashCode() : 0);
    }
```

part of `PartageDomain`

```
public class PartageDomain implements Serializable {
@EmbeddedId
    private PartageId partageId = new PartageId();
public PartageId getPartageId() {
        return partageId;
    }

    public void setPartageId(PartageId partageId) {
        this.partageId = partageId;
    }
...
public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        PartageDomain that = (PartageDomain) o;

        if (getPartageId() != null ? !getPartageId().equals(that.getPartageId()) : that.getPartageId() != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return (getPartageId() != null ? getPartageId().hashCode() : 0);
    }
```

the `PartageId` class:

```
@Embeddable

    public class PartageId implements Serializable {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @ManyToOne
        private FileDomain fileDomain;

        @ManyToOne
        private UserDomain userDomain;

        public FileDomain getFileDomain() {
            return fileDomain;
        }

        public void setFileDomain(FileDomain fileDomain) {
            this.fileDomain = fileDomain;
        }

        public UserDomain getUserDomain() {
            return userDomain;
        }

        public void setUserDomain(UserDomain userDomain) {
            this.userDomain = userDomain;
        }

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            PartageId that = (PartageId) o;

            if (fileDomain != null ? !fileDomain.equals(that.fileDomain) : that.fileDomain != null) return false;
            if (userDomain != null ? !userDomain.equals(that.userDomain) : that.userDomain != null)
                return false;

            return true;
        }

        public int hashCode() {
            int result;
            result = (fileDomain != null ? fileDomain.hashCode() : 0);
            result = 31 * result + (userDomain != null ? userDomain.hashCode() : 0);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your code is trying to achieve, but the `PartageId` class won't work since an `@EmbeddedId` class can't use relationship annotations...

Comment: nevertheless I found this in many demo and tutorials on the internet, so if you can explain more why it won't work? here is link to a tuto and there are a lot : [link](http://sieze.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/mapping-a-many-to-many-join-table-with-extra-column-using-jpa/)... thank you for help

Comment: If those tutorials work then perhaps there are implementations where it's OK, but the javadoc for `EmbeddedId` implies it's not OK - [Relationship mappings defined within an embedded id class are not supported.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html)

Comment: I had a quick look the tutorial you linked to - seems to work for some, but note the exception reported by one user (using EclipseLink) that incuded this text: _An embeddable class that is used with an embedded ID specification (attribute [pk] from the source [class model.ProductItem]) can only contain basic mappings._

Comment: I can't see why the hashCode() method is throwing a NullPointerException, perhaps its a problem in the `UserDomain` or `FileDomain` hashCode methods? Can you show the code for those?

Comment: I don't have such methods in the `UserDomain` and `FileDomain` classes, I don't think I should implement them in these classes ? Is I'm wrong in that ?? I just tried to do like discribed in the hibernate documentation, I'm not sure but I think so, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Your hashCode() method on `PartageDomain` is calling hashCode() on both those classes, but if you haven't overridden them the default implementation on `Object` shouldn't throw a NullPointerException...

Comment: I overriddan the hashcode method and update my post, the exception is always the same, Could someone has any idea ?? thank you

Comment: I had a look at the Hibernate code where the exception is being thrown - it's not because the hashCode() method is throwing an exception, it's because an object (possibly your ID object) is null. How are you setting the `partageId` on the `PartageDomain` class? Can you show the code where you create it?

Comment: I just have the @EmbeddedId in the PatageId property in PartageDomain, and just for the test I did PartageDomain p = new PartageDomain();
     p.getPartageId().setUserDomain(user);
     FileDomain f = new FileDomain();
     p.getPartageId().setFileDomain(f);
getPartageService().add(p); there is no null value in this